# live real-time collaboration using Emacs?

Tags: emacs, google-docs, org-mode, collaboration

Is there a package or tool that will allow me to do live online collaboration on a text document using Emacs? i.e. a tool that would allow me to connect with another user via the web, both open the same document, display two cursors, allow me to see their cursor and edits in real time, and allow them to see mine?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Rudel](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Rudel). I tried it a couple of times and it worked decently. It may not have everything you want (like seeing the other person's cursor), but that's not to say that couldn't be added.

Comment: I've used Rudel twice for a kind of intense timeline projects (during ICFP), and it indeed worked decently, but required much setup and fixing incompatibilities. It was written with different version of `eieio` than that currently shipped with Emacs. As of now, I don't think it will even launch w/o some poking around first.

Comment: That's fair. Just wanted to make it known as a potential option.

Answer (score 1):

For example, [Flootbits](https://floobits.com/) has Emacs support. You can install corresponding plugin via el-get...

Comment: Couple days ago I had to take a test using Flootbits (this was a request from the prospective employer). The result is that Emacs crashed several times during the session. But the worst thing wasn't the bugs, but the program's behaviour w/r to the files. It locked them up / changed them to read-only / stalled the minibuffer when I tried to create a file. In other words, the performance was horrible. Oh, and forgot to mention, it messed with selection face and `highlight-current-line` mode, so I couldn't see selection / cursor position.